# Show labels under slider ticks

Tags: javascript, angular-material

I am using the angular material md-slider. I would like to have labels under the ticks (e.g. '1', '2', '3') so the text, that would be shown in the balloon when panning through.

Anyone knows if this md-slider supports this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Should the label be positioned directly below the thumb and update its value according to the thumb position?

Comment: no i want to see all the values at all time. So I know which tick is what